# Will negative ESD strike pose any damages to I/O port connected to TVS?

Tags: esd, negative, io, tvs, shunt

I understand that bidirectional TVS can withstand both positive and negative ESD strikes, with the positive ESD current is shunted to Ground through TVS whereas negative ESD current is shunted to I/O port. My question is will this have any impact on I/O port when negative ESD strikes as I know that I/O port will be in use and there is no way to let the negative ESD current shunt to it. Wish to seek for clarification on this. Thanks a lot for any replies.

Answer (score 3):

The negative hit will actually end up shunted to ground through the built-in ESD protection clamps in the IC. Even if that protection wasn't there, the TVS would shunt the hit to ground, but it would clamp at the negative clamping voltage, below ground. The bidirectional TVS really isn't helping you on your negative hits. A unidirectional TVS would do the same thing, but clamp at just a diode drop below ground.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May I conclude as both positive and negative ESD strike eventually will end up shunted to the Ground?

Comment: Both will be shunted to ground, the TVS type is what will determine the voltage to which the GPIO pin is exposed.